# Response latency issue in Google Cloud VM that are connected with HTTPS Load Balancer (Global Load Balancer)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a NodeJS application installed in Google Cloud VM Instance at Center1-a,West1-a,East1-a and East4-a locations. Also I have create Instance Group for each of the VM and assigned HTTP Load Balancer (Global) to route the traffic between the Instance Group.

Note: I have not enabled CDN cache at Load Balancer.

I launched test from different region (Atlanta, Chicago, California, Dallas, NewYork). Each test ran for 20 iteration with 1 minute interval. The 90th percentile response time for each region stood at 4 second and average at 2 second.

When I looked into the access log of each hop, it seem their is a latency in connecting between the HTTP Load balancer and Instance Group / VM. I could reproduce this issue consistently.

Whereas when I run the test directly hitting each individual VM from all the above location, the 90th percentile response time stood at 230 millisecond and average at 145 millisecond.

Just to prove that, the issue is in connecting the LB and VM, I have also enabled CDN cache in the LB and ran the same test. The 90th percentile response time stood at 160 millisecond and average at 96 millisecond.

Why their is a response time latency issue when I hit through Global HTTP Load Balancer??

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: I am using free trial version of google cloud platform

Comment: I'm a member of Google Cloud Support, to solve the issue it would be necessary more information. I recommend you to open a new issue in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com). There you will be able to share more sensitive information like your project id or the name of the instance group, with this information we can dig deeper the cause of your issue.

Comment: I have similar issue. Our system uses HTTP Load balancer redirecting to GKE installed on Instance Groups. Every endpoint comming to GKE is received by ingress envoy proxy services, they're reporting latency is around 40ms, Network topology metric also reports the average value is ~40ms as well. But Load balancer is reporting a bunch of requests having 25s latency some days by some days. Could anyone confirm that the latency between balancer and Instance Groups being true? and share some ways to debug to fix them? I've seen cloud firewall log but having no routing latency info to refer :(